# Grease Pencil Visibility

Tags: grease-pencil

I am trying to use the grease pencil for the first time. When I try to create a stroke I see nothing at all. It is invisible. However, when I convert it to a geometry, I can see it. I am assuming that I should see the stroke as I am drawing it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked that "Grease Pencil Layers" is checked in the properties panel? (N in the 3D viewport)

Comment: Check color from the Grease Pencil palette, turn its opacity on

Comment: I had the exact same problem using an early 2.8 build, solved by moving to the greasepencil-object branch

Comment: wilks, what do you mean "moving to the greasepencil-object branch "?